# insert into sql server data base from html controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, database, sql-server-2008

i have a `<h1>` that has a news title in it and i want to insert the content of this `<h1>` into sql server 2008 database how can i do this  using c#

Comment: Move to stackoverflow... maybe after some editing?

Comment: I wonder where do you get the content of this `<h1>` from. Either edit your question, or it will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Put a server control between your html tag. For example:

In this way you can access the lblTitle.Text property from the code behind and then pass it to the database.